# Index a multi-dimensional numpy array using other numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array in (720, 720, 30) shape. Let's call this A. It is a 720*720 pixel image with 30 different layers. I want to take some points of this image for all the 30 layers. So, I have two other numpy arrays with shape (22,). Let's call them b and c. Now, I want to select all these points in all the layers. So, I use a code like this:

```
Z = A [B, C, ...]
```

I expect Z to be an array with shape (22, 22, 30).

I get an index error when I run the code:

```
IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type
```

How can I fix this problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you try `Z = A [B.astype(int), C.astype(int), ...]`

Comment: Thanks. It DID work!